# RDS crosstab: ERROR: permission denied for language c

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, amazon-rds, pivot, aws

We're currently using PostgreSQL 9.2 in our production database, we want to migrate to a new RDS instance, using PostgreSQL 9.4. However, we need to have permission to create a function, but only superuser can create functions on RDS and my user can't be granted as superuser.

```
CREATE FUNCTION crosstab50(text, OUT rownumber integer, OUT c1 text,...) 
    RETURNS SETOF record 
    LANGUAGE c 
    STABLE STRICT 
    AS '$libdir/tablefunc', 'crosstab';
```

But we're getting this error during our restore operation:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for language c
```

Comment: How to use the basic `crosstab()` function: [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RDS doesn't let you install arbitrary C functions. It's a restricted environment.

`crosstab` is part of the `tablefunc` extension. You may be able to `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc` if it's on the whitelist but you won't be able to add new variants, even if the underlying C function is already loaded and approved.

Comment: I was able to run `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc`. How can I use it now ? I'm new to postgres.

Comment: You can use all the predefined `crosstab` variants that come with `tablefunc`. See `\df crosstab*`. You cannot create new variants with different arguments. This is a limitation of AWS RDS PostgreSQL, not a limitation of PostgreSQL its self, because Amazon want to keep their RDS systems "sealed".

Comment: I see, thank you so much for your effort Craig!